# Two services cannot see each other through a swarm overlay

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I feel like this is simple, but I can't figure it out.  I have two services, consul and traefik up in a single node swarm on the same host.

```
> docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS         IMAGE                    PORTS
3g1obv9l7a9q        consul_consul       replicated          1/1                 progrium/consul:latest   
ogdnlfe1v8qx        proxy_proxy         global              1/1                 traefik:alpine           *:80->80/tcp, *:443->443/tcp

> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                              NAMES
090f1ed90972        progrium/consul:latest   "/bin/start -server …"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       53/tcp, 53/udp, 8300-8302/tcp, 8400/tcp, 8500/tcp, 8301-8302/udp   consul_consul.1.o0j8kijns4lag6odmwkvikexv
20f03023d511        traefik:alpine           "/entrypoint.sh -c /…"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       80/tcp
```

Both containers have access to the "consul" overlay network, which was created as such.

```
> docker network create --driver overlay --attachable consul
ypdmdyx2ulqt8l8glejfn2t25
```

Traefik is complaining that it can't reach consul.

```
time="2019-03-18T18:58:08Z" level=error msg="Load config error: Get http://consul:8500/v1/kv/traefik?consistent=&recurse=&wait=30000ms: dial tcp 10.0.2.2:8500: connect: connection refused, retrying in 7.492175404s"
```

I can go into the traefik container and confirm that I can't reach consul through the overlay network, although it is pingable.

```
> docker exec -it 20f03023d511 ash 
/ # nslookup consul

Name:      consul
Address 1: 10.0.2.2
/ # curl consul:8500
curl: (7) Failed to connect to consul port 8500: Connection refused

# ping consul
PING consul (10.0.2.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
```

However, if I look a little deeper, I find that they are connected, just that the overlay network isn't transmitting traffic to the actual destination for some reason.  If I go directly to the actual consul ip, it works.

```
/ # nslookup tasks.consul

Name:      tasks.consul
Address 1: 10.0.2.3 0327c8e1bdd7.consul
/ # curl tasks.consul:8500
<a href="/ui/">Moved Permanently</a>.
```

I could workaround this, technically there will only ever be one copy of consul running, but I'd like to know why the data isn't routing in the first place before I get deeper into it.  I can't think of anything else to try.  Here is various information related to this setup.

```
> docker --version
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962

> docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
cee3cdfe1194        bridge              bridge              local
ypdmdyx2ulqt        consul              overlay             swarm
5469e4538c2d        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
5fd928ea1e31        host                host                local
9v22k03pg9sl        ingress             overlay             swarm

> docker network inspect consul
[
    {
        "Name": "consul",
        "Id": "ypdmdyx2ulqt8l8glejfn2t25",
        "Created": "2019-03-18T14:44:27.213690506-04:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.2.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.2.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0327c8e1bdd7ebb5a7871d16cf12df03240996f9e590509984783715a4c09193": {
                "Name": "consul_consul.1.8v4bshotrco8fv3sclwx61106",
                "EndpointID": "ae9d5ef1d19b67e297ebf40f6db410c33e4e3c0266c56e539e696be3ed4c81a5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:02:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.2.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c21f5dfa93a2f43b747aedc64a343d94d6c1c2e6558d81bd4a52e2ba4b5fa90f": {
                "Name": "proxy_proxy.sb6oindhmfukq4gcne6ynb2o2.4zvco02we58i3ulbyrsw1b2ok",
                "EndpointID": "7596a208e0b05ba688f318814e24a2a1a3401765ed53ca421bf61c73e65c235a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:02:06",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.2.6/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-consul": {
                "Name": "consul-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "23e74716ef54f3fb6537b305176b790b4bc4132dda55f20588d7ce4ca71d7372",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:02:04",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.2.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4099"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "e11b9bd30b31",
                "IP": "10.8.0.1"
            }
        ]
    }
]

> cat consul/docker-compose.yml 
version: '3.1'

services:
  consul:
    image: progrium/consul
    command: -server -bootstrap
    networks:
      - consul
    volumes:
      - consul:/data
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=false"

networks:
  consul:
    external: true

> cat proxy/docker-compose.yml 
version: '3.3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:alpine
    command: -c /traefik.toml
    networks:
      # We need an external proxy network and the consul network
      #     - proxy
      - consul
    ports:
      # Send HTTP and HTTPS traffic to the proxy service
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    configs:
      - traefik.toml
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    deploy:
      # Deploy the service to all nodes that match our constraints
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.role==manager"
          - "node.labels.proxy==true"
      labels:
        # Traefik uses labels to configure routing to your services
        # Change the domain to your own
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:proxy.mcwebsite.net"
        # Route traffic to the web interface hosted on port 8080 in the container
        - "traefik.port=8080"
        # Name the backend (not required here)
        - "traefik.backend=traefik"
        # Manually set entrypoints (not required here)
        - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"

configs:
  # Traefik configuration file
  traefik.toml:
    file: ./traefik.toml

# This service will be using two external networks
networks:
  #  proxy:
  #  external: true
  consul:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two optional kernel configs CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_TCP and CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_UDP disabled in my kernel which, you guessed it, enable tcp and udp load balancing.

I wish I'd checked that about four hours sooner than I did.